# Python Path - open all files repeatdly, or extract its text

Tags: python, pyqt

I retrieve the path for a series of user-entered files.

```
files = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(w, 'Open File', '/')
print(files)
```

Output:

```
(['~/Desktop/f2.txt', '~/Desktop/f1.txt'], 'All Files (*)’)
```

It appears that the returned "files" object is a tuple.
I need to make it a list, loop through the given paths, and open each oneto extract its contents.
I also want to get rid of "  'All Files (*)' ", since I do not use it.

How can I put the paths in such a form to be easily opened, or retrieve their contents some other way?

Comment: Access the the first index of the tuple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you've described.
Don't worry about deleting "All Files"; simply do not use it.

```
files = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(w, 'Open File', '/')
print(files)
file_list = file[0]  # retrieve the list of files from the tuple.

# Iterate through the list;
#   open each file, in order.
for input_file in file_list:
    with open(input_file, 'r') as infile:
        # Read the entire file.
        contents = infile.read()
```

Comment: I tried this one, but there is an error:                                             Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/Desktop/Milestone4/mainInterface.py", line 168, in App
    contents = infile.read()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/codecs.py",
line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position
0: invalid start byte

Comment: You need to properly set your character setting.  You're using *UTF-8* (default for many environments) while your input is a another character set.  Try [HTML/XML encoding](https://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/character-encoding.html) and the `coding` meta-command.